# How to execute a source Code provided as a jar file?

Tags: java, ant, jar, cloud, manifest

Iam trying to test lattice monitoring framework in my virtual environment. I downloaded the source monitoring-src-0.6.4.jar from [lattice](http://clayfour.ee.ucl.ac.uk/lattice/). I executed it using

```
java -jar monitoring-src-0.6.4.jar
```

but iam getting the message like **no main manifest attribute, in monitoring-src-0.6.4.jar**

I checked MANIFEST.MF in META-INF it is like this

"Manifest-Version: 1.0

Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1

Created-By: 14.3-b01-101 (Apple Inc.)"

No main class is there. I dont know which one is the main class.

Then I downloaded the compiled version monitoring-0.6.4.jar from [lattice](http://clayfour.ee.ucl.ac.uk/lattice/) and executed

```
java -jar monitoring-0.6.4.jar
```

but gives me same error "no main manifest attribute, in monitoring-0.6.4.jar". I dont know what to do?? Could you please help me to solve this problem?? I dont know whether iam doing the correct thing.

Comment: You can't execute source code, it must be compiled.Download the compiled version from the link you gave.

Comment: I downloaded the compiled version monitoring-0.6.4.jar and executed java -jar monitoring-0.6.4.jar but gives me same error "no main manifest attribute, in monitoring-0.6.4.jar". I dont know what to do?? @Berger

Comment: As @DominicEU told you in his comment, you should find the documentation for the right way of using this particular library.

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute the source code. Do exactly what you're already doing, but download the [compiled version](http://clayfour.ee.ucl.ac.uk/downloads/monitoring-0.6.4.jar).

Comment: I downloaded the compiled version monitoring-0.6.4.jar and executed java -jar monitoring-0.6.4.jar but gives me same error "no main manifest attribute, in monitoring-0.6.4.jar". I dont know what to do??

Comment: Are you sure you're using the library correctly? Perhaps you should read their documentation. I found some [here](http://clayfour.ee.ucl.ac.uk/downloads/release-0.6.pdf)